# How to achieve maximum simulation accuracy in Bullet?

Tags: bulletphysics, bullet

I'm simulating rope to rope collision in Bullet and I'd like it to be as accurate as possible. I don't need the simulation to be real-time. Rope consists of rigid bodies connected using constraints(e.g. btConeTwistConstraint).

Which settings do I need to tweak for simulation to become more realistic and accurate?

From my experiments decreasing the 3rd parameter to 1/300 gives additional accuracy.

```
gDynamicsWorld->stepSimulation(SIMULATION_STEP_TIME, 1, 1.0f/60.0f);
```

Also increasing solver iterations count helps a bit:

```
btContactSolverInfo& info = dynamicsWorld->getSolverInfo();
info.m_numIterations = 50;
```

There are [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PfezSJB21vk) where people simulate [thousands](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FIPu9_OGFgc) of bodies in Blender. I'd like to achieve similar effect in a C++ app.

Comment: How is your rope "unrealistic" specifically?

Comment: rigid bodies jitter, the distance between two connected rigid bodies is noticeable, ropes sometimes penetrate through each other

Comment: Did you try a number that less than 1/300 e.g. 1/3000?  If you face problem from doing so, try enable double precision.  If you tried, let me know if it helps (or not).